# 3 Phase Motor Rectifier

Tags: motor, rectifier, generator, brushless-dc-motor

I have a [Turnigy Rotomax 50cc](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__17987__turnigy_rotomax_50cc_size_brushless_outrunner_motor.html) engine and I am trying to rectify it. I don't know whether it has delta or a wye winding style but I suspect that it is delta(Left Picture). [image]

This is what I have so far:

[image]

In my spice simulation I set the schematic up like this:[image]

OUTPUT:[image]

In my spice schematic I have 3 separate voltage sources set as sine waves with there negative terminals connected together. So I am trying to figure out how to hook up my rectifiers to an actual motor. My question is have I set it up right in my schematic? Do each of the motor phases attach to every other rectifier input?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**: Also the load is 50A nominal

Comment: What's wrong with using a regular 3 phase diode rectifier? Why all the drama of a mosfet solution?

Comment: Diode rectification is extremely inefficient compared to a mosfet solution and has the benefit of reduced voltage drop.

Comment: What ac voltage are you using.

Comment: Also, why are you connecting a motor to the input - do you mean generator?

Comment: The motor is 172kv and I can spin it at about 3000 with my gas engine so thats about 17.5Volts. Not sure what you mean connected to the input but yes I am building a generator.

Comment: What sort of frequencies are coming from the generator?

Comment: search in wikipedia for "vienna rectifier" may be that can help you.

Comment: Could this be a confused troll?  The data is not congruent at all.  Axis could you supply the make and model details of your motor, generator and load for better service.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your have tried to replicate three full-bridges (3 x 4 rectifying elements) when you only really needed to add one branch for a total of [6 rectifying elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier#Three-phase_bridge_rectifier) like so:

[image: Three-phase rectifier]

Comment: Diode rectification is extremely inefficient compared to a mosfet solution and has the benefit of reduced voltage drop.

Comment: Yes, this figure was meant to show the topology, in which you can replace diodes by MOSFETs, but then you have to control them with the proper sequence to rectify properly. I guess the OP was looking for a passive solution which would explain his more complicated topology.

Comment: I guess I could always build an active solution but I would prefer a passive solution which I think I have working hence the simulation but my question is about how to hook up a delta winding to my current schematic. BTW Thanks for the help so far!